# Cannot add styling to Select field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter-bootstrap in my rails app.

```
<%= f.select :rating, options_for_select([["Good","1"],["Average","2"],["Poor","3"]]), :class => "form-control" %>
```

But the `form-control` class is not working in select field

please help me to get the style working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [look at the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select), the `class` key is part of the last argument, which is a hash. Before that there's an options hash:

```
f.select :rating, options_for_select([["Good","1"],["Average","2"],["Poor","3"]]), {}, class: "form-control"
```

Here's an example using the options hash:

```
f.select :rating, options_for_select(...), { include_blank: "Choose" }, class: "foo"
```